# spi driver works on pi 3 and pi 4, but not on pi cm4

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, spi, driver

I have a spi driver for an nrc7292.  When I load it on a pi3 or 4 it works every time, but when I load it on a cm4 it only loads correctly about half the time.  What could possibly be different?  Once loaded it works great.  Below is the output of a failed insmod command.

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/nrc.ko  hifspeed=10000000 spi_bus_num=0 spi_cs_num=0 spi_gpio_irq=5 spi_polling_interval=0 fw_name=uni_s1g.bin auto_ba=1 sw_enc=1 listen_interval=1000
[   57.032406] start FW 330
[   57.238227] nrc-cspi spi0.0: SPI transfer timed out
[   57.243265] spi_master spi0: failed to transfer one message from queue
[   57.250102] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   57.254756] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 34 at ../newah_driver-custom/nrc-hif-cspi.c:364 _c_spi_read_regs+0x208/0x230 [nrc]
[   57.265317] Modules linked in: nrc(O) iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 8021q garp stp llc snd_soc_hdmi_codec v3d raspberrypi_hwmon gpu_sched brcmfmac brcmutil bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_isp(C) i2c_brcmstb bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) v4l2_mem2mem videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 spi_bcm2835 videobuf2_common vc4 snd_soc_bcm2835_i2s snd_bcm2835(C) cec vc_sm_cma(C) videodev mc drm_kms_helper drm rpivid_mem snd_soc_simple_card drm_panel_orientation_quirks snd_soc_simple_card_utils pps_gpio snd_soc_core syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops backlight snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine nvmem_rmem uio_pdrv_genirq uio snd_pcm snd_timer snd sch_fq_codel snd_i2smic_rpi(O) mac80211 libarc4 cfg80211 rfkill fuse ipv6
[   57.334815] CPU: 0 PID: 34 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G         C O      5.15.32-v8 #1
[   57.342749] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0 (DT)
[   57.349196] Workqueue: events nrc_check_start [nrc]
[   57.354145] pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   57.361118] pc : _c_spi_read_regs+0x208/0x230 [nrc]
[   57.366064] lr : _c_spi_read_regs+0x19c/0x230 [nrc]
[   57.371004] sp : ffffffc00978b950
[   57.374320] x29: ffffffc00978b950 x28: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
[   57.381476] x26: ffffffc009563848 x25: ffffff80fb78b305 x24: 0000000000000001
[   57.388630] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffffff8045646000 x21: 0000000000000020
[   57.395783] x20: 0000000000000010 x19: ffffffc00978bc88 x18: ffffffc08978b4d7
[   57.402935] x17: 0000000000000001 x16: 0000000000000001 x15: 076d07200765076e
[   57.410088] x14: 076f072007720765 x13: 076d07200765076e x12: 076f072007720765
[   57.417240] x11: 0720072007200720 x10: 0000000000000000 x9 : ffffffc00881029c
[   57.424393] x8 : 0000000000000004 x7 : 0000000000000003 x6 : ffffffc009379000
[   57.431545] x5 : ffffffc009379238 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : ffffff8045641b38
[   57.438697] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : ffffff8040328000 x0 : 00000000000000ff
[   57.445849] Call trace:
[   57.448297]  _c_spi_read_regs+0x208/0x230 [nrc]
[   57.452892]  c_spi_read_regs+0x34/0x70 [nrc]
[   57.457225]  spi_wait_ack+0x54/0xb0 [nrc]
[   57.461295]  nrc_fw_check_next_frag+0x108/0x140 [nrc]
[   57.466407]  nrc_download_fw+0x2fc/0x380 [nrc]
[   57.470909]  nrc_check_start+0x63c/0x790 [nrc]
[   57.475412]  process_one_work+0x1dc/0x490
[   57.479436]  worker_thread+0x144/0x470
[   57.483192]  kthread+0x144/0x160
[   57.486430]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[   57.490014] ---[ end trace 5f765400c22e14eb ]---
[   57.494784] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   57.499422] kernel BUG at ../newah_driver-custom/nrc-fw.c:193!
[   57.505261] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[   57.510756] Modules linked in: nrc(O) iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 8021q garp stp llc snd_soc_hdmi_codec v3d raspberrypi_hwmon gpu_sched brcmfmac brcmutil bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_isp(C) i2c_brcmstb bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) v4l2_mem2mem videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 spi_bcm2835 videobuf2_common vc4 snd_soc_bcm2835_i2s snd_bcm2835(C) cec vc_sm_cma(C) videodev mc drm_kms_helper drm rpivid_mem snd_soc_simple_card drm_panel_orientation_quirks snd_soc_simple_card_utils pps_gpio snd_soc_core syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops backlight snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine nvmem_rmem uio_pdrv_genirq uio snd_pcm snd_timer snd sch_fq_codel snd_i2smic_rpi(O) mac80211 libarc4 cfg80211 rfkill fuse ipv6
[   57.580222] CPU: 0 PID: 34 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        WC O      5.15.32-v8 #1
[   57.588152] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0 (DT)
[   57.594598] Workqueue: events nrc_check_start [nrc]
[   57.599556] pstate: 60000005 (nZCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   57.606529] pc : nrc_fw_check_next_frag+0x12c/0x140 [nrc]
[   57.611992] lr : nrc_fw_check_next_frag+0x108/0x140 [nrc]
[   57.617452] sp : ffffffc00978bcb0
[   57.620768] x29: ffffffc00978bcb0 x28: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
[   57.627922] x26: ffffffc009563848 x25: ffffff80fb78b305 x24: 0000000000000001
[   57.635075] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffffff804541f680 x21: ffffff8045791fc0
[   57.642228] x20: ffffff804560d200 x19: ffffff804541f580 x18: ffffffc08978b4d7
[   57.649380] x17: 0000000000000001 x16: 0000000000000001 x15: 076d07200765076e
[   57.656533] x14: 076f072007720765 x13: 076d07200765076e x12: 076f072007720765
[   57.663686] x11: 0720072007200720 x10: 0000000000000000 x9 : ffffffc001254908
[   57.670838] x8 : ffffff8040328000 x7 : 0000000000000003 x6 : ffffffc009379000
[   57.677990] x5 : ffffffc009379238 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : 00000000000004f6
[   57.685142] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 00000000fffffffb
[   57.692295] Call trace:
[   57.694742]  nrc_fw_check_next_frag+0x12c/0x140 [nrc]
[   57.699856]  nrc_download_fw+0x2fc/0x380 [nrc]
[   57.704359]  nrc_check_start+0x63c/0x790 [nrc]
[   57.708862]  process_one_work+0x1dc/0x490
[   57.712887]  worker_thread+0x144/0x470
[   57.716643]  kthread+0x144/0x160
[   57.719881]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
[   57.723472] Code: d4210000 52800000 17ffffd8 d4210000 (d4210000) 
[   57.729574] ---[ end trace 5f765400c22e14ec ]---
[   57.734196] note: kworker/0:1[34] exited with preempt_count 1
[   57.740544] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   57.745187] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at kernel/rcu/tree.c:613 rcu_eqs_enter.constprop.0+0xf4/0x110
[   57.754007] Modules linked in: nrc(O) iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 8021q garp stp llc snd_soc_hdmi_codec v3d raspberrypi_hwmon gpu_sched brcmfmac brcmutil bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_isp(C) i2c_brcmstb bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) v4l2_mem2mem videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 spi_bcm2835 videobuf2_common vc4 snd_soc_bcm2835_i2s snd_bcm2835(C) cec vc_sm_cma(C) videodev mc drm_kms_helper drm rpivid_mem snd_soc_simple_card drm_panel_orientation_quirks snd_soc_simple_card_utils pps_gpio snd_soc_core syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops backlight snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine nvmem_rmem uio_pdrv_genirq uio snd_pcm snd_timer snd sch_fq_codel snd_i2smic_rpi(O) mac80211 libarc4 cfg80211 rfkill fuse ipv6
[   57.823477] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G      D WC O      5.15.32-v8 #1
[   57.831147] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0 (DT)
[   57.837592] pstate: 200000c5 (nzCv daIF -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   57.844565] pc : rcu_eqs_enter.constprop.0+0xf4/0x110
[   57.849631] lr : rcu_eqs_enter.constprop.0+0x1c/0x110
[   57.854694] sp : ffffffc009373d20
[   57.858010] x29: ffffffc009373d20 x28: 00000000011c0018 x27: ffffffc008e5a5d8
[   57.865163] x26: ffffffc009380040 x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000000
[   57.872317] x23: ffffffc008ea7050 x22: ffffffc0090ac878 x21: ffffffc0093789e0
[   57.879470] x20: ffffffc009378aec x19: ffffff80fb7887c0 x18: 0000000000000000
[   57.886622] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 x15: 0000007f942f1b78
[   57.893775] x14: 0000000000000000 x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0000000000000001
[   57.900928] x11: ffffff80fb7dbb80 x10: 00000000000019d0 x9 : ffffffc008b96f58
[   57.908081] x8 : ffffffc009381a70 x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffffffc009379000
[   57.915233] x5 : ffffffc009379238 x4 : 0000000000000001 x3 : ffffffc00909c008
[   57.922385] x2 : 4000000000000000 x1 : ffffffc0093797f8 x0 : 4000000000000002
[   57.929538] Call trace:
[   57.931986]  rcu_eqs_enter.constprop.0+0xf4/0x110
[   57.936705]  rcu_idle_enter+0x1c/0x30
[   57.940379]  default_idle_call+0x38/0x19c
[   57.944398]  do_idle+0x258/0x2a0
[   57.947632]  cpu_startup_entry+0x30/0x90
[   57.951561]  rest_init+0xec/0x100
[   57.954888]  arch_call_rest_init+0x1c/0x28
[   57.958997]  start_kernel+0x6bc/0x6fc
[   57.962669]  __primary_switched+0xa4/0xac
[   57.966689] ---[ end trace 5f765400c22e14ed ]---
```

Could this have something to do with a shared hardware resource with the emmc?

Answer (score 0):

Wifi uses spi0.0 on the CM4.. that's a conflict.

Comment: Very interesting.  This project is on the back back back burner atm, so I wont be able to check, but that was keeping me up at night.